# Group by with condition - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I need to filter some information from my data grid, such as average surviving age and proportion of living men and women

I try with this

```
tit.groupby(by=['Survived'])['Yes']
```

But I can't filter this way

Comment: Erfan, if I want to put one more condition, for example, tit ['Survived'] == 'Yes' and tit ['Sex'] == 'Women'

Comment: Thank you, put as answer, for me to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably working with the titanic dataset, and for this filter you don't need groupby.

First filter:

```
tit.loc[tit['Survived'] == 'Yes']
```

Second filter:

```
tit.loc[(tit['Survived'] == 'Yes') & (tit['Sex'] == 'Women')]
```